# Simplify or FullSimplify doesn't work on Gamma function

Tags: special-functions

I have this expression:

```
Gamma[n - 0.691 + 2.35 I] Gamma[n - 0.691 - 2.35 I]
```

which returns real values for all $n$. However, neither Simplify nor FullSimplify can reduce it to a form without involving $i$. Is there a way to force these commands to do a better job?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! What exactly do you want as a final formula? If you are bothered by ``+ 0. I`` in the result, then use [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html), for example: ``Gamma[n - 0.691 + 2.35 I] Gamma[n - 0.691 - 2.35 I] /. n -> 3 // Chop``

Comment: "Is there a way to force these commands to do a better job?" -- This seems to assume there is a better result that they fail to produce. What is the result you expect? Or identity that they fail to apply?

Comment: If `n` being real is a safe assumption, perhaps use `Re[Gamma[n - 0.691 + 2.35 I] Gamma[n - 0.691 - 2.35 I]]`.

Comment: Maybe this little helps: $$\Gamma (n-i x) \Gamma (n+i x)=\frac{\Gamma (n)^2}{\prod _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(1+\frac{x^2}{(n-1+k)^2}\right)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that $\overline{\Gamma(x)}=\Gamma(\overline{x})$, you can rewrite your expression as

```
Abs[Gamma[n - 0.691 + 2.35 I]]^2
```

which is manifestly real (even though it still contains an `I`). Honestly, I would be very surprised if you found a useful expression without any `I`, so this might be the best you can do.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to achieve this in Mathematica? ``FullSimplify[Gamma[z] Gamma[Conjugate[z]] == Abs[Gamma[z]]^2]`` does return ``True``, yet ``FullSimplify[Gamma[z] Gamma[Conjugate[z]]]`` doesn't give the simpler form (which has smaller ``LeafCount``).

Comment: @Domen unfortunately I don't... So far, I have had very limited success when trying to get Mathematica to simplify expressions containing `Conjugate` - it knows the relevant relations if you ask it directly (as you did), but it never seems to use that knowledge to simplify anything

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that the imaginary part is so small that you are "sure" it is zero.  If so return just the real part:

```
\[Epsilon] = 10^-10;
g[n_] := Gamma[n - 0.691 + 2.35 I] Gamma[n - 0.691 - 2.35 I]
h[n_] := If[Im[g[n]] < \[Epsilon], Re[g[n]], g[n]]
```

`g[55.5]` returns
`1.04586*10^142 + 0. I`

`h[55.5]` returns
`1.04586*10^142`